# onUserLocationChange changes React Native Maps region

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native

I'm using MapView from 'react-native-maps'

I can't get the "showsMyLocationButton" to show, so I'm implementing my own.

I want do this without using React Native's geolocation because I find it to be slower than react-native-maps prop showsUserLocation. I use onUserLocationChange event which returns the coordinates. However when firing the onUserLocationChange event and setting a state which contains the userLocation, it automatically updates the region without me explicitly asking for it.

This is my code:

```
display_my_location(coordinate){
  alert("region changed")
  this.setState({
    region: {
      latitude: coordinate.latitude,
      longitude: coordinate.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.004,
      longitudeDelta: 0.004
    },
  });
}

setUserLocation(coordinate){
  //alert("User location changed MAP SHOULDNT MOVE")
  this.setState({
    userLocation: {
      latitude: coordinate.latitude,
      longitude: coordinate.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.004,
      longitudeDelta: 0.004
    }
  })
}

<MapView
      style={styles.map}
      showsMyLocationButton={true}
      onUserLocationChange={locationChangedResult => this.setUserLocation(locationChangedResult.nativeEvent.coordinate)}
      initialRegion={this.state.region_amon}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      region={this.state.region}
      mapType={this.state.map_style}
      showsCompass = {true}
      showsMyLocationButton={true}
      chacheEnabled={false}
      zoomEnabled={true}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can fix this by deleting the `region` prop from the `MapView` altogether. If you need to have the map's bounding box change programmatically you can attach a ref to the map and update in `componentDidUpdate` using the appropriate MapView method here:

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#methods

Comment: I don't have region prop in MapView and the problem still exist.

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround for the above issue, we can have a custom icon on the map. After clicking on the custom icon trigger a method. In the method get the current location coordinates using [Geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/geolocation) and fire **animateToRegion** and pass the coordinates.

**Step 1:** Declare mapRef

```
const mapRef = useRef(null);
```

**Step 2:** Assing mapRef to MapView

```
<View style={{flex: 1}>
<MapView
       ref={mapRef}
       ...........
 />
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={currentLocationHandler}>
  <MaterialIcons
    name="my-location"
    size={24}
    color="black"
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

**Step 3:** currentLocationHandler method

```
const currentLocationHandler = () => {
<!-- Get location coordinates using GeoLocation npm package -->
    let currentRegion = {
      latitude: latitude from geolocation,
      longitude: longitude from geolocation,
      latitudeDelta: 0.001,
      longitudeDelta: 0.001,
    };
    mapRef.current.animateToRegion(currentRegion, 3 * 1000);
}
```

I hope the above steps help you to solve the issue